# C++ Passing std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< foo > >

Tags: c++, class, stl, vector, shared-ptr

I am currently learning the basics of the STL and boost libraries and wanted some assistance. Let me first describe where I am at I want to construct a vector of shared_ptrs of say some class foo. Previously I had an array or pointers and was required to use `new` and `delete` to handle memory and thought the transition to vectors and smart pointers would be a good idea. I currently have something like:

```
class foo{
 ....
}

int main(){
 std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< foo > > vec_ptr;
 vec_ptr.push_back(boost::make_shared<foo>);
 ....
}
```

Now I would like to know how to best pass this vector in two situations:
 - Into a function.
 - Into the constructor of a class object (which via the initialisation list initialises the object.

Into a function I am guessing that it is best passed by reference, as in:

```
void func(std::vector< boost::shared_ptr < foo > >& vec_ptr_in_func){
  ....
}
```

Into a class constructor I am not sure my initial guess was something like

```
class vec_class{
 vec_class(std::vector< boost::shared_ptr < foo > >& vec_ptr_in_class_)
  : vec_ptr_in_class(vec_ptr_in_class_){...}
}
```

But this seems to be giving errors along the lines of:

```
no matching function for call to vec_class::vec_class(std::vector< boost::shared_ptr < foo >, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr< foo > > >)
```

Comment: What is the function, and what is the constructor, going to do with the vector? A lot depends on that.

Comment: I think you want to make your constructor public. By default it's private.

Answer (score 0):

1. For a function pass it like

   ```
   // If you intend to modify the vec_ptr_in_func   
   void func(std::vector< boost::shared_ptr < foo > >& vec_ptr_in_func){

   }


   // If you intend to not modify the vec_ptr_in_func   
   void func(const std::vector< boost::shared_ptr < foo > >& vec_ptr_in_func){

   }
   ```
2. Pass it by const-reference for the constructor.